# send dropdwon selected list item in form data to the server

Tags: javascript, html

How to send the selected dropdown list item to the server along with the form data on pressing submit button?

html

```
<span class="dropdown" >
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="ops" type="button" id="menu2" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Condition
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"   role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" >
                <li  role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Not Equals</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Equals</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Greater Than</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Less Than</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contains</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
```

Comment: You have a ul that's being styled as a drop down list.  There are several ways in which to capture the clicked on list item.  What have you tried?

Comment: @devlincarnate using select and then having options as the drop down items helps in retrieving the selected item in req.body but i want to retrieve the selected item if the dropdown items are in the form of li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is create a input hidden, then pass value of dropdown option to it! See my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="stacksubmit.html">
    <span class="dropdown" >
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="ops" type="button" id="menu2" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Condition
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu"   role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" name="dropdown">
            <li  role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Not Equals</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Equals</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Greater Than</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Less Than</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contains</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="optionvalue" id="optionvalue">
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
<script>
  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#optionvalue').val($(this).text());
  });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then, add the php page get submit, you can get that value by:$option = $_POST['optionvalue']; echo($option);

Comment: Yeah, I got the point. Btw i use nodejs and i retrieved this value in req.body.optionvalue. Thanks for the help though!!